# Get info from Yelp Api

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, yelp-fusion-api

I am hooking into the Yelp Api to get data which I am then showing in a card format. However, my issue is that I can't seem to pass the yelp data into this array in order to pull the yelp data. How do I do this? How can I do this on a scale of 20 restaurants?

This is how I am getting the information:

```
//
//  Get Restaurants.swift
//  Pickt
//
//  Created by Morris Richman on 8/29/21.
//

import Foundation
import Moya

private let apiKey = "<api key>"

enum YelpService {
    enum BuisnessesProvider: TargetType {
        var baseURL: URL {
            return URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses")!
        }
        
        var path: String {
            switch self {
            case .search:
                return "/search"
            }
        }
        
        var method: Moya.Method {
            return .get
        }
        
        var sampleData: Data {
            return Data()
        }
        
        var task: Task {
            switch self {
            case let .search(loc):
                return .requestParameters(parameters: ["location": loc, "term": "restaurants", "limit": 1], encoding: URLEncoding.queryString)
            }
        }
        
        var headers: [String : String]? {
            return ["Authorization": "Bearer \(apiKey)"]
        }
        
        case search(loc: String)
        
    }
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let businesses: [Business]
}

struct Business: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: URL
    let rating: Double
    let url: String
}

struct RestaurantListViewModel {
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: URL
    let id: String
    let rating: Double
    let url: String
}


extension RestaurantListViewModel {
    init(business: Business) {
        self.name = business.name
        self.id = business.id
        self.imageUrl = business.imageUrl
        self.rating = business.rating
        self.url = business.url
    }
}
```

Calling the get func:

```
let service = MoyaProvider<YelpService.BuisnessesProvider>()
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        service.request(.search(loc: "98117")) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                let root = try? self.jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
                let viewModels = root?.businesses.compactMap(RestaurantListViewModel.init)
                print(viewModels!)
                print(Restaurants.mock)
                Restaurants.viewModels = viewModels!
//                print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []))
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error = \(error)")
            }
        }
```

And finally retrieving it:

```
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: URL
    let id: String
    let rating: Double
    let url: String
    
    static var viewModels: [RestaurantListViewModel] = []
    static var mock: [Restaurants] = [
        Restaurants(name: "Silverio's Mexican Kitchen", imageUrl: URL(string: "https://mainsite-prod-cdn.azureedge.net/partner-images/432257/micrositeimage_p1.jpg")!, id: "hjkhjhjh", rating: 2, url: "https://google.com"),
        Restaurants(name: "Taqueria La Esquinita", imageUrl: URL(string: "https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/x-KCQ7osmvBWLA9WpPdO_Q/o.jpg")!, id: "hjdha", rating: 3, url: "https://google.com")
    ]
```

I think I got the answer to this using CDYelpFusionKit. My only problem is when I install through Cocoapods, I get this error:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/mcrich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pickt-fpbpwbgjikipuabwpwmkowpgeelv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pickt.app/Frameworks/CDYelpFusionKit.framework': 1) Target 'Pickt' has copy command from '/Users/mcrich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pickt-fpbpwbgjikipuabwpwmkowpgeelv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CDYelpFusionKit.framework' to '/Users/mcrich/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pickt-fpbpwbgjikipuabwpwmkowpgeelv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pickt.app/Frameworks/CDYelpFusionKit.framework' 2) That command depends on command in Target 'Pickt': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

Comment: removed my comment to secure code. thanks @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @PrabhatKasera you better remove this comment too, because it's easy to see in the edit history when you know what to look for=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, it was getting the data and appending it, The content just wasn't showing, because it would load before that was done.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using the "Business" model to save in the Array.
which already have value you want to copy in "RestaurantListViewModel"

```
>     let array = [Business]()
>     let service = MoyaProvider<YelpService.BuisnessesProvider>()
>             let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
>             jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
>             service.request(.search(loc: "98117")) { result in
>                 switch result {
>                 case .success(let response):
>                     let root = try? self.jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
>                     array.append(contentsOf:root.businesses)
>     //                print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []))
>                 case .failure(let error):
>                     print("Error = \(error)")
>                 }
>             }
```

also, use limit and offset query parameter to get the page wise info and use array.count() as offset and limit is 20 by default in yelp API

[image]

Comment: didn't work, I got the error: "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'"

Comment: please check once more using contentsOf